# How to Best Create Separate Subscribers and User Experience

Tags: posts, email, directory, subdomains, community

I use a Bluehost (hosted) version of Wordpress 5.5.1 with Genesis for my blog (recipe and faith posts). I use the Mailchimp service for my email subscribers. I want to create a separate community (faith for caregivers) within my blog where users can subscribe and see posts only related to that community. Is this possible? What is the best way to do this? Subdirectory? Subdomain? Or can I accomplish this with just a separate page? I am not highly technical and looking for the easy method possible.

Comment: Do you want to make this a completely separate blog, or just e.g. posts with a certain category in the main blog? Does the MailChimp plugin email new posts to subscribers? I guess that will depend on the plugin then: hopefully it will support more than one list, and the ability to filter which posts get emailed to the list by category?

Comment: I was planning to do posts with a certain category in the main blog vs a separate blog. The Mailchimp plugin does email new posts to subscribers. It also has the ability to create email campaigns specific to certain subscribers. The questions are: 1) Which of these formats should I create (page, subdirectory etc..) to direct them to see the post? 2) Once this is created, can I a subscriber widget be tied to this category of user that would distinguish them from other subscribers? If so, I think I can distinguish them in MailChimp for a mail campaign specific to them.

Comment: Cathy - your question is off-topic for this site (see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, before this question ends up marked as closed, it sounds like you need a membership plugin (if you want certain users to see certain posts). I won't push my own, and will just say there are plenty of good possibilities out there, as well as places to ask this type of question where it is more "on topic." Hope you find what you're looking for.